# Ordering a mysql style datetime stamp with meta_query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a custom post type field that I am storing data in called football_game_datetime.

Example format and values for this field are examples like: "2013-10-31 14:00:00", "2013-09-16 20:00:00", "2013-09-30 22:00:00".

The code I am using is the following, but it isn't doing what I thought it should be doing:

```
$mypost =
array(
    'post_type' => 'football_games',
    'meta_query' => array(
           array(
                'order'=>'DESC',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'meta_key' => 'football_game_datetime'
           )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
```

Answer (score 3):

`'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` will try to force the value to a number by adding 0. In other words, `"2013-09-30 22:00:00"+0` When I tested that both PHP and MySQL converted the string to `2013`, which is not what you want.

That particular date format, and only that date format, will sort correctly if you just leave it alone. That is, it will sort matching a human calendar. Don't use `meta_value_num`. You don't have a number. You have a string. Just use `meta_value`.

Secondly, `order` and `orderby` are not valid inside a `meta_query` those need to be outside the `meta_query`, and in fact, I don't think you need the `meta_query` at all.

```
$mypost =
array(
    'post_type' => 'football_games',
    'order'=>'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'football_game_datetime'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
```

What you have is essentially, [this example from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters):

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'price' ) );
```